# pH and acid value relation for an organic chemical

Tags: organic-chemistry, ph

Would there be a general relation between the pH (say, as measured by a pH strip) and the titration-measured "acid value" of a organic chemical?

The acid value is typically defined as "the mass of potassium hydroxide (KOH) in milligrams that is required to neutralize one gram of chemical substance."

If you determine the acid value of something which technically does not have an acidic moeity e.g. (say) an oil or benzaldehyde I suppose what you are tracking is the residual acidity of some impurities?

Would pH then be a function of ill defined parameters like some ppm amount of residual water etc. (since pH would be strictly defined for an aqueous solution).

For context: The situation I have is an liquid organic chemical where the spec typically is an upper limit of the acid value. But someone started wondering whether there would be a pH strip correlation.

Comment: There is no strict relation between the two, even if we work in water and pH is well defined.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to confirm! Trying to make sure I didn't miss something.